# Parse JSON strings as tables using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings, parsing, json

Needed a simple CSV file that had headers and no nesting of data to consume in Tableau. The JSON file I was consuming had nested dictionaries and lists (which sometimes had in themselves nested lists/dictionaries).

The output is a pipe delimited format (because free text fields have comments in that mess things up) with nested fields having both the original dictionary key plus any lower keys as the headers.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Sep 14 12:22:02 2018

@author: redim_learning 
"""
import sys
import time


class parse_json():
    # this class handles parsing json data, once it's been read in as a string using the json library
    def __init__(self):
        return None

    #this writes out dictionaries within the main json dictonary 
    def write_dict(self, sub_dict, dict_name,  f, str_dict):
        try:
            str_dict = str_dict + ('"%s"' % (str(dict_name)))  #commar?!
        except:
            print ('key not passed correctly', str(dict_name)) 
        try:
            for second_key, second_value in sub_dict.items():
                if type(second_value) == dict:
                    print ('dictionary within dictionary')
                    print( second_key)
                    write_dict(item[key],second_key,f,str_dict)

                str_value = str(second_value)
                #clean up characters 
                if '\n' in second_key or '\r' in str_value:
                    str_value = (str_value).replace('\n','').replace('\r','').replace(chr(34),chr(39))

                str_dict = str_dict + (', "%s"' % str_value)
            return str_dict[:len(str_dict)]
        except:
            print('dict write out did not work\n' , str_dict )
            print('item[key] is ', sub_dict)

            #print('second key:%s, second value:%s' %(second_key, second_value))
    #this function manages to parse a list that is stored within the original json dictionary
    def write_list(self, item, key,  f, list_str):
        # don't write a new line, that will be done later
        #write first item in the list in current row
        for list_value in item[key]:
            if type(list_value) ==str:
                list_str = list_str +(list_value.replace('\n','').replace('\r','').replace(chr(34),chr(39)) + ", ")
            elif type(list_value) ==dict:
                #sys.stdout.write("\nkey: %s, type(item): %s" % (key, type(item)))
                #print('\nlist_value is :' + list_value)
                sys.stdout.flush()
                sys.stdout.flush()
                sub_dict = list_value
                list_str = list_str + write_dict(sub_dict,dict_name, f, list_str)

        return list_str[:len(list_str)-2]

    #this is needed to know when to add a line feed to the total string
    def find_last_field(self, item):
        #loop through all fields and return last header value
        for header,value in item.items():
            last_key = header
            #print (header)
        return last_key

    #parses headers
    def write_headers(self, item,last_header):
        header_list = ''
        object_list = ''
        for h,v in item.items():
            if type(v) ==dict:
                for sub_header in v.items():
                    if type(sub_header) == tuple:
                        object_list = object_list + '"' + h + '_' + sub_header[0]+ '",' 
                    else:
                        object_list = object_list + '"' + sub_header + '",' 
            elif type(v) ==list:
                for rec in v:
                    object_list = object_list + '"' + h + "'," 
            else:
                header_list = str(header_list) + '"'  + h+ '",' 
        # return the full header string, but exclude the last commar

        return header_list + object_list[:len(object_list)-1]


    def parse_json_file(self, data, f, page):
        full_str = ''
        last_header = ''
        for item in data:
            try:
                sys.stdout.write("\rPage %i, record %s of %i records" %(page+1, str(item['id']), len(data))) #Writes out progress for user 
                sys.stdout.flush()
            except TypeError:
                sys.stdout.flush()
                sys.stdout.write("\rprogress is progressing ")
                sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.flush()
            #when you're only looking at one record
            if type((item))==str:
                item = data
            dict_str = ''
            list_str = ''
            item_str = ''
            if last_header == '' and page == 0:
                #determine the last header so you know when to write the line return
                last_header  = find_last_field (item)
                #write out a the headers in the first row                    
                f.write(write_headers(item, last_header) + "\n")

            for key, value in item.items():
                #print (item_str )
                #print (key,value, type(value))
                #try:
                if type(item[key]) == dict:
                    #print('is dict')
                    try:
                        dict_str = dict_str + write_dict(value, key, f, dict_str)
                    except:
                        sys.stdout.write("\rdictionary didn't write properly ")
                        sys.stdout.flush()
                elif type(item[key]) == list:
                    #print('is list')
                    try:
                        list_str  = list_str + write_list(item, key,  f, list_str)
                    except:
                        sys.stdout.write("\rlist didn't write properly ")
                        sys.stdout.flush()
                elif type(item[key])==tuple:
                    item_str = item_str + '"' + value[1] +'",'
                elif type(item[key])==int:
                    item_str = item_str +'"' + str(value) +'",'  
                elif value == 'True' or value == 'False' or type(value) ==bool:
                    #print('is bool')
                    item_str = item_str + '"' + str(value).lower() +'",'
                    #print (item_str)
                elif type(value) == str:
                    #print('is str')
                    item_str = item_str +'"' + value.lower().replace('\n','').replace('\r','').replace(chr(34),chr(39)) +'",'  
                    #print (item_str)
                elif type(value) == None or value == None:
                    #print('is str')
                    item_str = item_str +'"",'  
                else:
                    print ('not added %s as is type %s' % (value,  type(value)))
            full_str = full_str + item_str + dict_str + list_str + "\n"
                #print (full_str)
            time.sleep(0.5) #Wait so we don't overload instance with too many api requests

            #break
        return (full_str)
```

Comment: perhaps add an example input file and how this code is supposed to be called .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the csvkit package from Pypi to accomplish that. Here's one of the tools from csvkit to convert json to csv in python: https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/scripts/in2csv.html

Edit:

So making the answer a bit more discriptive, a messy json like this one:

```
[
   {
      "a1":"1",
      "a2":"2",
      "aa":[
         "a",
         "a"
      ],
      "bb":[
         {
            "b1":1,
            "b2":2
         },
         {
            "b1":1,
            "b2":2
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "a1":"1",
      "a2":"2",
      "aa":[
         "a",
         "a"
      ],
      "bb":[
         {
            "b1":1,
            "b2":2
         },
         {
            "b1":1,
            "b2":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Would become a very simple csv file like this one:

```
a1,a2,aa/0,aa/1,bb/0/b1,bb/0/b2,bb/1/b1,bb/1/b2
1,2,a,a,1,2,1,2
1,2,a,a,1,2,1,2
```

by just running this command:

```
pip install csvkit
in2csv -f json < file.json > file.csv
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.

Comment: Links can rot - please include the relevant content in the answer itself and provide the link as added reference material.